# Excel: combine multiple rows into single row based on first column which could have empty cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the formula to combine the column B into a single row.

for e.g. A17.9 Tuberculosis of nervous system, unspecified.

[image: sample]

what makes it tricky it could be N number of line for the description

[image]

need help in figuring out the formula. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in `A1:B11`, in `C1`:

`=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,IF(LOOKUP(ROW(A$1:A$11),ROW(A$1:A$11)/(A$1:A$11<>""),A$1:A$11)=A1,B$1:B$11,""))`

and copied down.

It goes without saying that the last row referenced within the ranges passed (11 here) should be kept to a minimum.